# ios/swift dispatch queues - global and main queue concepts

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

So if I were to do something heavy, and then update the UI, would this be the best way of doing it?

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    // Do something heavy here, such as adding 10000 objects to an array

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Update UI here after the heavy lifting is finished, such as tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this one of the ways you can use to avoid blocking the main thread , but there is many other alternatives such as using `DispatchGroup` for chaining asynchronous tasks ,`OperationQueue` or even create your own queue and inside it do heavy work and hand the UI things to main thread , but to keep in mind the global queue is only one queue if you find that there is a lot of calls to it , it's better to create a new helper one